# Split XML response into pages

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, jaxb

I want to split XML response into pages because I have too many XML items to send back. I tried this:

***XML request:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<reconcile>
  <start_date>2018-04-08T11:02:44</start_date>
  <end_date>2019-10-08T11:02:44</end_date>
  <page>1</page>
</reconcile>
```

***JAXB:***

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "reconcile")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Reconcile {

    @XmlElement(name = "start_date")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(LocalDateTimeXmlAdapter.class)
    private LocalDateTime start_date;
    @XmlElement(name = "end_date")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(LocalDateTimeXmlAdapter.class)
    private LocalDateTime end_date;
    @XmlElement(name = "page")
    private String page;
    ...../// getters and setters
}
```

***SQL query:***

```
public List<PaymentTransactions> transactionsByDate(LocalDateTime start_date, LocalDateTime end_date, Merchants merchant, Terminals terminal) throws Exception {

        String hql = "select e from " + PaymentTransactions.class.getName() + " e where e.created_at >= ? and e.created_at <= ?";
        Query query = entityManager.createQuery(hql).setParameter(0, start_date).setParameter(1, end_date);
        List<PaymentTransactions> paymentTransactions = (List<PaymentTransactions>) query.getResultList();
        return paymentTransactions;
}
```

Return XML:

```
 List<PaymentTransactions> paymentTransactions = transactionsService
                    .transactionsByDate(reconcile.getStart_date(), reconcile.getEnd_date(), merchant, terminal);

            ReconcilePaymentResponses pr = new ReconcilePaymentResponses();
            pr.setPage("1");
            pr.setPages_count("10");
            pr.setPer_page("4");
            pr.setTotal_count(String.valueOf(paymentTransactions.size()));

            for (int e = 0; e < paymentTransactions.size(); e++) {
                PaymentTransactions pt = paymentTransactions.get(e);

                ReconcilePaymentResponse obj = new ReconcilePaymentResponse();
                obj.setTransaction_type(pt.getType());
                pr.getPaymentResponse().add(obj);
            }

            return pr;
```

XML Response:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<payment_responses page="1" per_page="4" total_count="5" pages_count="10">
    <payment_response>
        <transaction_type>Type</transaction_type>
    </payment_response>
    <payment_response>
        <transaction_type>Type</transaction_type>
    </payment_response>
    <payment_response>
        <transaction_type>Type</transaction_type>
    </payment_response>
    .........
</payment_responses>
```

I would like somehow to split `<payment_response>....</payment_response>` into pages in order to reduce memory overhead. For example when I send 1 I would like to return the first 10.

How I can implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you think about something like this?  I'm sorry it is untested code but something like this should work.

I created a new PageInfo class to store the paging info.  Added a query to get the total number of rows and set my page_info.  Then limited the number of results from your query.  Finally set the values to ReconcilePaymentResponse.

```
Class PageInfo {
    int current_page;
    int page_count;
    int per_page;
    int total_page;

    //constructor
    public PageInfo(int current_page, int page_count, int per_page) {
        //assign them
    }
    //getters
    //setters
}
```

SQL Query:

```
public List<PaymentTransactions> transactionsByDate(LocalDateTime start_date, LocalDateTime end_date, Merchants merchant, Terminals terminal,
    PageInfo pageInfo) throws Exception {

    //figure out number of total rows
    String count_hql = "select count(*) from " + PaymentTransactions.class.getName() + " e where e.created_at >= ? and e.created_at <= ?";
    Query count_query = entityManager.createQuery(count_hql);
    int count = countQuery.uniqueResult();

    //figure out total pages
    int total_page = (int)Math.ceil(count/(double)pageInfo.getPerPage());
    pageInfo.setTotal_Page(total_page);

    String hql = "select e from " + PaymentTransactions.class.getName() + " e where e.created_at >= ? and e.created_at <= ?";
    Query query = entityManager.createQuery(hql)
        //set starting point
        .setFirstResult((pageInfo.getCurrentPage()-1) * pageInfo.getPerPage)
        //set max rows to return
        .setMaxResults(pageInfo.getPerPage)
        .setParameter(0, start_date).setParameter(1, end_date);
    List<PaymentTransactions> paymentTransactions = (List<PaymentTransactions>) query.getResultList();
    return paymentTransactions;
}
```

Return XML:

```
        //initialize PageInfo with desired values
        PageInfo page_info = new PageInfo(1,10,4);
        List<PaymentTransactions> paymentTransactions = transactionsService
            .transactionsByDate(reconcile.getStart_date(), reconcile.getEnd_date(), merchant, terminal, page_info);  // pass in page_info

        ReconcilePaymentResponses pr = new ReconcilePaymentResponses();
        pr.setPage(page_info.getCurrentPage());
        pr.setPages_count(page_info.getPageCount());
        pr.setPer_page(page_info.getPerPage());
        pr.setTotal_count(String.valueOf(paymentTransactions.size()));

        for (int e = 0; e < paymentTransactions.size(); e++) {
            PaymentTransactions pt = paymentTransactions.get(e);

            ReconcilePaymentResponse obj = new ReconcilePaymentResponse();
            obj.setTransaction_type(pt.getType());
            pr.getPaymentResponse().add(obj);
        }

        return pr;
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there some way to use only one SQL query?

Comment: For example can you show me example with SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 5,10; https://www.petefreitag.com/item/451.cfm

Comment: hibernate doesn't have "limit" but .setFirstResult((pageInfo.getCurrentPage()-1) * pageInfo.getPerPage) and .setMaxResults(pageInfo.getPerPage) does the same thing.  MaxResults in this case is the 5 and FirstResult is the 10

Comment: I use JPA. Is there any solution for `limit`?

Comment: I'm saying setFirstResult and setMaxResult is the same as limit.  So we are not pulling everything when we return a page.